# Computer produces continuous beep on startup

Tags: bios

When starting up my computer, this is what I hear:
[[YouTube video]](http://www.youtube.com/watch_private?v=7lxW38W6FCQ&sharing_token=BepHNrei9RP2eoJasijNAA==)

Basically, it's a continuous beep. What does this mean and, more importantly, what can I do about this? I think this PC uses AMIBIOS, but I'm not sure since I can't check.

Comment: Often when troubleshooting it is helpful to know what happened before it started malfunctioning; if your question has been answered please disregard.
What changed from the first time you heard the beep?
Did you it shut down normally, or did it crash? If it crash what were you doing when it happened, any other open windows or apps? Did you open the case, or plug or unplug something in the back of the PC?
Upgrade or install new software?
Have children or pets that might have done something accidentally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like OVERHEATING. check the fan and if need be, replace the heat sink paste for the CPU.

Comment: I don't assemble my own computers, so I'm not familiar with that kind of stuff. Could you please explain this a little further or give me a good resource that guides me through this process?

Comment: here is a youtube video of how to do it.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OB1hxxKdec
i thought a visual aid would help more. this is a old computer so just pay attention to removing the heatsink and the applying the paste.

Answer (score 2):

Can't listen to youtube here, but:

Continuous beep is usually either a bad fan or a bad keyboard.
Start by replacing the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be bad RAM. Usually when there is incompatible or bad ram installed it will beep. Have you installed any new hardware? Maybe the Power supply inst supplying enough voltage? Bad Fan?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should consult your mainboard's manual. Any beep codes and their meaning should be documented there.

For AMIBIOS the list can be found [here](http://www.ami.com/support/doc/AMIBIOS8_Checkpoint_and_Beep_Code_List_PUB.pdf).

Comment: It doesn't seem to say anything about a continuous beep.

Answer (score 1):

I would venture a guess to say it's either the video card or the keyboard not being plugged in (without knowing the exact model of your motherboard).

If the keyboard is fully plugged in, then I'd look to see if your video card requires any extra power connectors from the power supply to be plugged in to work properly. If you post more information about your motherboard or your computer, we'll be able to help you out more.